# How do I get Input Positive Button value in Runtime?

Tags: unity, c#

In *Unity* in InputManager I assigned <kbd>R</kbd> Button to "Restart" name.

Now that property (Restart) has another property with a key "Positive Button" and string value "R".

[image]

In the game I can show notice to user: "click <kbd>R</kbd> for Restart!"

But what if user will change that key in the start config window? For example   from <kbd>R</kbd> to <kbd>T</kbd> button.

[image]

Now the game should display notice: "click <kbd>T</kbd> for Restart!"

**Question:** How do I get changed Positive Button value by name "Restart" via script in Runtime? Is it possible?

---

p.s. in Editor I can do this:

```
SerializedObject inputManager = new SerializedObject(AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath("ProjectSettings/InputManager.asset")[0]);
SerializedProperty axisArray = inputManager.FindProperty("m_Axes");

for (int i = 0; i < axisArray.arraySize; ++i) {
    var axis = axisArray.GetArrayElementAtIndex(i);
    var axisName = axis.FindPropertyRelative("m_Name").stringValue;
    if (axisName == "Restart") {
        restartButtonValue = axis.FindPropertyRelative("positiveButton").stringValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

But it allows to use it only in the Editor. Because it uses `UnityEditor.dll`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, **this isn't possible right now**.
Like you said, it uses the Editor library.
The only option left is to use an entierely different system to manage all inputs. Take a look on the asset store for system like [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/57332).

Comment: `Unfortunatly, this isn't possible right now.` - it is 100% ? )) Why do developers not do that functionality? How do they explain that? And what for start config window needs then? .............Thanks for the link, but without Start Config Window I can make Input Manager myself =))